# c++ How to find the minimum number of elements from a vector that sum to a given number

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I want to find the minimum number of elements from an array that their sum is equal to the given number.

Comment: Can the array have negatives?

Comment: It's like solving world peace and happiness in C++. First you find a solution, then you code it up in C++ (that's the easy step).

Comment: it sounds like a homework assignment. at least try it.

Comment: @dmg I did tried to sort them from the highest to the lowest and then add them up but it's not the proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an easy dynamic programming task.

Suppose that there are *N* elements in the array *A* and you want to get the minimum number of elements which sum is *S*. Then we can easily solve the problem with *O(N x S)* time complexity.

Consider *dp[i][j]* - the minimum number of elements among first *i* elements which sum is *j*, *1 <= i <= N* and *0 <= j <= S*. Then for *A[i] <= j <= S*:

*dp[i][j] = min(infinity, dp[i - 1, j], 1 + dp[i - 1][j - A[i]])*.

We can assume that *dp[0][0] = 0*, *dp[0][j] = infinity* for *0 < j <= S*.

Comment: @M.Alaggan So you think that we cannot solve NP-hard problems with dynamic programmic, don't you?

Comment: Your formulation could use some work to account for the case where the sum is negative.

Comment: I feel you're trying to describe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) pseudo-polynomial time solution to subset sum.

Comment: @AndyG it's some variation of a subset sum problem. You're absolutely right, this solution should be slightly amended in case of negative sums.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to solve it recursively.

```
find_sum(goal, sorted_list) {
    int best_result = infinity;
   for each (remaining_largest : sorted_list){
    result = find_sum(goal - remaining_largest, sorted_list_without_remaining_largest) + 1;
    if result < best_result then best_result = result;
  }
  return best_result;
}
```

There are many ways to optimize this algorithm and may be fundamentally better algorithms as well, but I was trying to keep it very simple.

One optimization would be to store the best combination to get to a given number in a hash table.   The naive algorithm suffers from the same drawbacks as a recursive fibonacci solver in that it is constantly re-solving duplicate sub-problems.

I haven't actually run this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
  // value, num values to sum for value
  map<int,int> cache;

// returns -1 on no result, >= 0 is found result
int find(int goal, vector<int> sorted_list, int starting_position = 0) {

  // recursive base case
  if (goal== 0) return 0;

  // check the cache as to not re-compute solved sub-problems
  auto cache_result = cache.find(goal);
  if (cache_result != cache.end()) {
   return cache_result->second;


    // find the best possibility
    int best_result = -1;
    for (int i = starting_position; i < sorted_list.size(); i++) {
         if (sorted_list[starting_position] <= goal) {
            auto maybe_result = find(goal- sorted_list[starting_position], sorted_list, i++); 
            if (maybe_result >= 0 && maybe_result < best_result) {
                best_result = maybe_result + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // cache the computed result so it can be re-used if needed
    cache[goal] = best_result;

    return best_result;
}
```

Comment: how can I translate for each into simple for?

Comment: @C.Cristi i wrote some C++ code that might work.. but I haven't had a chance to run it

Answer (score -1):

Try ordering it ascending and while you iterate through it make a temporary sum in which you add every element until you reach the required sum. If by adding a new element you go over the sum continue without adding the current element. Try something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<nr_elem;i++)
  minimum = 0;
  temp_sum=0;
  for(j=0;j<nr_elem;j++){
     if(temp_sum + elem[j] > req_sum)
         *ignore*
     else
         temp_sum+=elem[j];
         minimum+=1;}
  if(global_min < minimum)
      global_min = minimum;
```

Not the most elegant method or the most efficient but it should work

Comment: 7, 6, 4, 3   goal is 14 - your algorithm fails, the answer is 3